# Entity filtering for Jax-rs using RestEasy

Tags: jax-rs, entity, filtering, resteasy

I am building restful services using rest easy. I have few services which have to address different views of same Model/Resource.

Ex:- Model is Project
Short View :- I have to return only few members of the resource
Detailed View - I have to return all members of the resource

Want to know if there is jax-rs specification or Rest EASY API to support this.
If not please throw some pointers on how to acheive it.

Let me know if i have to provide more background

Comment: You could use [Jackson's JSON Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews).